# Auto create links in text following a pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to to search through the document text and where it finds a pattern of `0000/0`, `0000/00` or `0000/000` (where `0` can be any number) it automatically wraps that text in

```
<a href="http://example.com/something-0000/00">0000/00</a>
```

What I found for auto linkers are only when text is a URL, so it doesn't really help with what I need.

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first by doing some research on the subject and making an attempt to write the code. If you have issues with that code, then feel free to ask a question requesting debugging help. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple regexp approach

```js
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/(\d{4}\/\d{1,3})/g, 
  '<a href="http://example.com/something-$1">$1</a>')
```

```html
Some text 0000/0 and this 1234/56 and that  7777/666
```

Comment: Great. I'm a regex noob, so "simple regex approach" is not that simple to me. But this is exactly what I needed. Thank you

Comment: @AlexZmed regexp: `\d` means digit, `\d{4}` means exact 4 digits, `\/` this is slash escape character, `\d{1,3}` means minimum 1 and maximum 3 digits. The braces `(...)` means that is group `$1` (we use group number in second part of replace parameter ('template' string))

Comment: Thank you for the follow up. I need more of these since the client want to replace text in an online html book with links where certain things match. I can use this example to build the rest of the functions, so I appreciate the help.

Comment: @AlexZmed This site [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/JQrZXI/2) is good to test, learn and explain regexp (window on the top right and bottom right)

Answer (score 1):

A simple regex pattern would do the trick.

```
text.replace(/(0000\/[0-9]{1,3})/gm, `<a href="http://example.com/something-$1">$1</a>`);
```

This will look for 0000/ followed by numbers between 0 and 9, 1 to 3 times.